# Between DATE and TODAY

Tags: sql, oracle

On Oracle SQL Developer I am trying to use this code below as base.
However, with this code all the possible data are shown, but I would like to filter the results

```
WHERE oh.ship_by_date BETWEEN '01/01/2021' AND current date
```

(In system DATE is shown as dd/mm/yyyy)

I tried to put this filter but I do not understand why the results are still coming out with all ship by dates, hence are not filtered. Where would I have to put the filter, and how could I write it correctly? Thank you so much for your help.

```
select  
  q1.order_id, q1.status,  q1.ship_by_date, q1.shipped_date,
  count(q1.order_id) lines, sum(q1.qty_ordered) qty, 
  q1.user_def_num_4, q1.user_def_note_2, q1.name, q1.order_type, q1.seller_name, 
  sum(q1.qty_shipped), 
  q1.work_group, q1.creation_Date
from
(
  SELECT 
    OH.ORDER_ID, OH.STATUS, TO_CHAR( OH.SHIP_BY_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  ship_by_date,
    TO_CHAR(OH.SHIPPED_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') shipped_date, ol.QTY_ORDERED, 
    oh.user_def_num_4, oh.user_def_note_2, oh.name, oh.order_type, ol.qty_shipped,
    oh.seller_name, oh.creation_date, oh.work_group
  FROM V_ORDER_HEADER Oh
  left JOIN v_order_line ol on oh.order_id = ol.order_id
  union all
  (
    SELECT 
      OH.ORDER_ID, OH.STATUS,  TO_CHAR( OH.SHIP_BY_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  ship_by_date,
      TO_CHAR(OH.SHIPPED_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') shipped_date, ol.QTY_ORDERED, 
      oh.user_def_num_4, oh.user_def_note_2, oh.name, oh.order_type, ol.qty_shipped,
      oh.seller_name, oh.creation_date, oh.work_group
    FROM V_ORDER_HEADER_archive Oh
    left JOIN v_order_line_archive ol on oh.order_id = ol.order_id
    union
    SELECT 
      OH.ORDER_ID, OH.STATUS, TO_CHAR( OH.SHIP_BY_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  ship_by_date,
      TO_CHAR(OH.SHIPPED_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') shipped_date, ol.QTY_ORDERED, 
      oh.user_def_num_4, oh.user_def_note_2, oh.name, oh.order_type, ol.qty_shipped,
      oh.seller_name, oh.creation_date, oh.work_group
    FROM V_ORDER_HEADER_archive_2 Oh
    left JOIN v_order_line_archive ol on oh.order_id = ol.order_id
  )
) q1
group by 
  q1.order_id, q1.status, q1.ship_by_date,  q1.shipped_date, 
  q1.NAME, q1.order_type, q1.user_def_num_4, q1.user_def_note_2, q1.seller_name,
  q1.work_group, q1.creation_Date
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your DBMS? You should always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS in order to get answers that work for you.

Comment: Why do you convert `oh.ship_by_date` to a string (`TO_CHAR`)? And where do you want to place that `WHERE` clause? `WHERE oh.ship_by_date BETWEEN '01/01/2021' ...` looks like a bad idea, because you are comparing a date (I do hope that column type is `DATE`) with a string. Use a date literal instead (provided your DBMS supports this): `WHERE oh.ship_by_date >= DATE '2021-01-01'`.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your time, I am just beginning, so I am giving my best to learn. My DBMS is Oracle SQL Developer. Also, the code I am using as a base has been made by somebody who worked in our company in the past. However, now I am trying to use it applying this filter with a date. And in the first place for my knowledge the code is still too complicated, so I do not know where I should even put the filter "WHERE" to get the data I would like. Right now I am checking tutorials on youtube to understand UNION ALL and TO CHAR.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the following `WHERE` clause with every query part, i.e. after each `LEFT JOIN` clause.

```
WHERE oh.ship_by_date >= DATE '2021-01-01' AND oh.ship_by_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
```

(The `+ 1` is short for `+ INTERVAL '1' DAY` by the way.)

The other option would be to place the following `WHERE` clause after unioning all the tables (i.e. after `) q1`.

```
WHERE q1.ship_by_date >= DATE '2021-01-01' AND q1.ship_by_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
```

But this would probably be much slower, because you are dealing with all the data first rather than just with the date range you are interested in, and then only in the very end you apply that date range limit. So, while this alternative may be considered more readable and better maintainable, it is probably still a bad idea.

Then, you are using a constant `2021-01-01` here. Will this be still the same value when you run the query next year? If you want the current year instead, you can use

```
WHERE oh.ship_by_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') AND oh.ship_by_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
```

At last a remark on your data: You are dealing with history tables here. The more current entries are in `V_ORDER_HEADER` and `V_ORDER_LINE`. The older rows have been moved to `V_ORDER_HEADER_ARCHIVE`, `V_ORDER_HEADER_ARCHIVE_2` and `V_ORDER_LINE_ARCHIVE`. From the names all these are views, not tables, so I don't know what magic happens behind the scenes here. Generally it is often a better idea to work with partitioned tables, so you work with only one table instead of with a current table and a history table in your query and the DBMS then accesses the partitions it needs to fulfill the task, which is usually only the current partition(s), while old partitions are seldom accessed. And old data can be removed much quicker by merely dropping old partitions.

Comment: Thank you so much Thorsten. I have tried it and it works perfectly. Also, thank you so much for having explained in detail the context and the alternative for the SYSDATE, YEAR as well. I am very very thankful and am happy to learn more. In the future I will make sure to share the DBMS. Also, I might test this once more tomorrow and come back at you with few other questions for a couple changes I would like to make. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that immediately come to mind. In both cases i would recommend attempting to cast your ship_by_date as a datetime and then comparing against your (hardcoded?) 2021 date and current date.

E.g:

```
WHERE CAST(oh.ship_by_date AS datetime) 
BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND GETDATE()
```

Or

```
WHERE CAST(oh.ship_by_date AS datetime) > '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
and CAST(oh.ship_by_date AS datetime) < GETDATE()
```

EDIT - I just realised you are also turning your oh.ship_by_date to a CHAR using TO_CHAR in your selects. Try taking that part out too. E.g.

```
select  q1.order_id, q1.status ,  q1.ship_by_date, q1.shipped_date,
count(q1.order_id) lines, sum(q1.qty_ordered) qty, q1.user_def_num_4, q1.user_def_note_2, q1.name, q1.order_type, q1.seller_name, sum(q1.qty_shipped), q1.work_group, q1.creation_Date
from
(SELECT OH.ORDER_ID, OH.STATUS, OH.SHIP_BY_DATE, TO_CHAR(OH.SHIPPED_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') shipped_date, ol.QTY_ORDERED, 
oh.user_def_num_4, oh.user_def_note_2, oh.name, oh.order_type, ol.qty_shipped, oh.seller_name, oh.creation_date, oh.work_group
FROM V_ORDER_HEADER Oh
left JOIN v_order_line ol on oh.order_id = ol.order_id
--where oh.order_id = '0082693218') */
union all
(SELECT OH.ORDER_ID, OH.STATUS, OH.SHIP_BY_DATE, TO_CHAR(OH.SHIPPED_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') shipped_date, ol.QTY_ORDERED, 
oh.user_def_num_4, oh.user_def_note_2, oh.name, oh.order_type, ol.qty_shipped, oh.seller_name, oh.creation_date, oh.work_group
FROM V_ORDER_HEADER_archive Oh
left JOIN v_order_line_archive ol on oh.order_id = ol.order_id
union
SELECT OH.ORDER_ID, OH.STATUS, OH.SHIP_BY_DATE, TO_CHAR(OH.SHIPPED_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') shipped_date, ol.QTY_ORDERED, 
oh.user_def_num_4, oh.user_def_note_2, oh.name, oh.order_type, ol.qty_shipped, oh.seller_name, oh.creation_date, oh.work_group
FROM V_ORDER_HEADER_archive_2 Oh
left JOIN v_order_line_archive ol on oh.order_id = ol.order_id))
--where oh.order_id = '0082693218') */
q1

WHERE CAST(oh.ship_by_date AS datetime) 
BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND GETDATE()

group by q1.order_id, q1.status, q1.ship_by_date,  q1.shipped_date, 
q1.NAME, q1.order_type, q1.user_def_num_4, q1.user_def_note_2, q1.seller_name, q1.work_group, q1.creation_Date
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am trying to apply this, however I get error "invalid datatype". I am currently trying to find other solutions, but should you have any further suggestion I am very glad to hear.

Comment: @CC-SQLBeginner What is the DataType of your oh.ship_by_date column? Can you give an example data from oh.ship_by_date? Can you also try to use CONVERT function? E.g. CONVERT(datetime, oh.ship_by_date)

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is one of the types from Ship by date from OH: 08/07/2021

Comment: @CC-SQLBeginner Did you try CONVERT function? I also added some details to my answer, have you seen this too?

Comment: Thank you. I have seen the edit in your comment, and tried it. Yet I still receive the invalid error. As for CONVERT, I do not know this function, so I would know even know where to put it in the first place. I am about to watch a tutorial on YouTube to understand better how to use it. Thanks again, I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: @CC - SQL Beginner: You hadn't tagged your request with your DBMS. L.Newell didn't ask. Now you have told us your DBMS is Oracle. L.Newell's syntax looks like SQL Server. This is another SQL dialect. And this is why it is so important to tag SQL requests with the DBMS in question.

Comment: I apologize. Will make sure to include that in my future threads.